# How to find the first question asked by me?

Tags: discussion, questions, sorting

Is there any way to find out the "first question asked by me", without scrolling all the way down in `tab=questions&sort=newest`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a built in way to do this, but using [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/), it's really simple:

You can use the [following query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/860893/my-oldest-question):

```sql
SELECT TOP 10 Id AS [Post Link]
FROM Posts
WHERE PostTypeId = 1 AND OwnerUserID = ##UserId##
ORDER By CreationDate ASC
```

Of course, TOP 10 can be adjusted to show more questions.

Answer (score 3):

If your first question was any good (scoring 1) go to your Badges in your profile and find your [Student](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2/student?userid=484082) badge.

Or

If using SEDE is too fancy, try this [Stack API call](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-on-users#order=asc&sort=creation&ids=484082&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true), `/users/{id}/questions` and sort ascending on creation.

For your convenience here it is in a stack snippet:

```js
function getFirstQuestion(userid, site) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  // prepare a GET for the API call, parameters go into the url
  xhr.open('get', 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/'+ userid + '/questions?order=asc&sort=creation&site=' + site);
  xhr.addEventListener('load', d => {
    // add the item values to the link
    function buildLink(item) {
      var a = document.getElementById('link');
      a.setAttribute('href', item.link);
      a.innerHTML = item.title;
    }
    // parse it, whi needs error handling
    var list = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    if (list.items && list.items.length > 0) {
      buildLink(list.items[0]);
    }

  });
  // make the actual call
  xhr.send();
}

function buildLink2(userid) {
  var a = document.getElementById('badgelink');
  a.setAttribute('href', 'https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2/student?userid='+ userid);
  a.innerHTML = userid
}


// hookup the button
document.getElementById('go').addEventListener('click', e => {
  // get the entered userid
  var userid = document.getElementById('userid');
  // who needs to validate input these days
  getFirstQuestion(userid.value, 'stackoverflow');
  buildLink2(userid.value);
});
```

```html
<label>Your userid:</label>
<input id='userid' type='text' value='484082' />
<button id='go'>Get First Question</button>
<p>
First Question aksed: 
</p>
<a id='link'></a>

<hr>
Or see if your first question earned you a Student badge
<a id='badgelink'></a>
```

Comment: Bonus points if you can come up with something elegant to find the first question even if it's deleted :)

Comment: @JonClements nice try but that won't work form the API, nor from SEDE ... as the badge table doesn't include the postid that awarded the badge (when applicable). Had that been the case we could have looked for the Student badge and its postid. That is possible from the user profile though ...

Comment: I like this.. :D

Comment: @rene and the student badge is first question scoring 1 or more and won't necessarily be the first asked...